# Runtime error when reversing string in C

Tags: c, string

I don't understand why am I getting runtime error when I use `s[j]!='\0'` but when I use `*temp!='\0'` it works perfectly fine. Can anyone explain?

```
void reverseWords(char *s)
{
  char *word_begin = s;
  char *temp = s; /* temp is for word boundry */
  int i=0,j=0;

  while( s[j]!='\0' )
  {
    j++;
    if (s[j] == '\0')
    {
      reverse(s, i, j-1);
    }
    else if(s[j] == ' ')
    {
      reverse(s, i, j-1);
      i = j+1;
    }
  }     
}
```

Comment: Because `s` is a pointer, you have to do `*s != '\0';`

Comment: Not enough information to know what is wrong, do you do something with temp, and what about reverse ? have you tried to run through a debugger ?

Comment: s[j] is just equal to *(s+j), check if your J out-bound!

Comment: dvhh here is the complete: 1. https://ideone.com/WuhBPE (not working) 2. https://ideone.com/MA12dN (working)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is not in that function. If you check your `reverse` function, you never increment `i` or decrement `j` so it will run forever.

A debugger is a helpful tool and would have shown this immediately.

Comment: thanks! You are right. I should have used debugger :/